# Table of Values

Tags: tables, formatting, matrices

How can something like this be done in MacTex:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possibility using an `array`; numbering for the first column is done automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{myrow}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{>{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow}c|*{5}{c}}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
& 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
& 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
& 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
& 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
& 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{myrow}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c|*{5}{c}}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots &  \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots &  \\
3 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots &  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  &  \\
n &  &  &  &  &  \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much, Gonzalo Medina.

Comment: @Trancot You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept the answer if you consider it solved your problem ;-)